# Two same class types in entity framework class issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I am implementing feature that allows users to follow each other.
I have database tables:

```
User{UserId, FirstName, LastName etc.}
Followings{FollowerUserId, FollowingUserId, CreatedOnDate etc.}
```

So I added EF class:

```
public class Follow
    {
        [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
        public Guid FollowerUserId { get; set; }
        [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
        public Guid FollowUserId { get; set; }        
        public DateTime CreatedOnDate { get; set; }

        public virtual User Follower { get; set; }
        public virtual User Following { get; set; }
    }
```

The last two virtual properties couse issue.
When I call:

```
var model = con.Follows.Where(x => x.FollowerUserId == uid);
```

I get following exception:

```
Invalid column name 'Following_UserId'.
```

The issue is probably caused because of two User objects in one class. Any idea how to workaround this? 

**UPDATE**

```
public class User
    {

        public Guid UserId { get; set; }
        ...
        public virtual ICollection<Follow> Following { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Follow> Followers { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: it doesn't seem right for me to put both the userID and the navigation property, you should put only one of them, otherwise EF can't make the connection between them

Comment: Can you explain better I am not sure how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the reason is that the foreign key properties (`FollowerUserId` and `FollowUserId`) and navigation properties (`Follower` and `Following`) do not respect the naming conventions so that EF is unable to recognize the first properties as foreign keys. You can fix the problem by specifying the FK properties explicitly using the `[ForeignKey]` attribute:

```
public class Follow
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1), ForeignKey("Follower")]
    public Guid FollowerUserId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 2), ForeignKey("Following")]
    public Guid FollowUserId { get; set; }        

    public DateTime CreatedOnDate { get; set; }

    public virtual User Follower { get; set; }
    public virtual User Following { get; set; }
}
```

**Edit**

A least the second property doesn't respect the naming convention, the first one looks OK. So, alternatively you can fix the problem by renaming the second FK property `FollowUserId` into:

```
public Guid FollowingUserId { get; set; }
```

...because the navigation property is called `Following`.

**Edit 2**

About your UPDATE: You need to add the `[InverseProperty]` attribute to tell EF which navigation properties belong together:

```
public class Follow
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1), ForeignKey("Follower")]
    public Guid FollowerUserId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 2), ForeignKey("Following")]
    public Guid FollowUserId { get; set; }        

    public DateTime CreatedOnDate { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Followers")]  // refers to Followers in class User
    public virtual User Follower { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Following")]  // refers to Following in class User
    public virtual User Following { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this solves my issue in follow class. Just one more thing if it is not a problem I also tried to add collection of followings/followers to User class (I added it in my question update) and I again get similar error: Invalid column name 'User_UserId'.