# asp.net value ' 1 ' is invalid

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to work on asp.net mvc5 project where I have two models Post and Game.

It will work like this, you post on Post and you choose which game you made, and you also choose which game you are going to do next. As you can see on this image I've gotten so you get a DropDownList of the games that is in the database:
[image]

How ever when I press Create I get an error Saying value ' 1 ' is invalid.
[image]

And I am not to sure why this would occur as in my database I save these values as int's.[image]
**Post Model:**

```
public class Post
    {
        [Key]
        public int PostId { get; set; }

        //URL
        [Display(Name = "URL")]
        [StringLength(80)]
        [DataType(DataType.Url)]
        [Required]
        public string Url { get; set; }
        //User
        [Display(Name = "User")]
        public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

        //Game
        [Display(Name = "Game")]
        public virtual Game GameId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Next Game")]
        public virtual Game NextGameId { get; set; }

        //Time
        private DateTime? _date;
        public DateTime? Date
        {
            get
            {
                if (_date == null || _date.ToString() == "1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM")
                {
                    return _date = DateTime.Now;
                }
                return _date;
            }
            set
            {
                _date = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Post Controller:**

```
 // GET: Posts/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.GameId = new SelectList(db.Games, "GameId", "GameTitle");
        ViewBag.NextGameId = new SelectList(db.Games, "GameId", "GameTitle");

        return View();
    }

    // POST: Posts/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "PostId,Url,GameId,NextGameId,Date")] Post post)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Posts.Add(post);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.GameId = new SelectList(db.Games, "GameId", "GameTitle", post.GameId);
        ViewBag.NextGameId = new SelectList(db.Games, "GameId", "GameTitle", post.NextGameId);

        return View(post);
    }
```

**Game Model:**

```
public class Game
{
 [Key]
    public int GameId { get; set; }
    public string GameTitle { get; set; }
}
```

And my **Posts/Create view** where I create the dropdowns:

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.GameId, "GameId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("GameId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GameId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NextGameId, "NextGame", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("NextGameId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NextGameId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Works as you told it to... Hint: `[Display(Name = "Game")]  public virtual Game GameId { get; set; }` should be `int?` not `Game`

Comment: Why did you change your models from your previous questions - `GameId` and `NextGameId` properties are now typeof `Game` (a complex object). Change them back to `int`. And DO NOT name your `ViewBag` property the same as the model property

Comment: Calling the navigation properties `GameId` and `NextGameId` is confusing.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Because in the last question someone did mention it would be better to do it this way, so I tried and I failed.

Comment: Change the properties back to `int`. In the controller use `ViewBag.GameList = new SelectList(db.Games, "GameId", "GameTitle")` (only one required) and in the view use `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.GameId, (SelectList)ViewBag.GameList , new { @class = "form-control" })` and ditto for `NextGameId`

Comment: @StephenMuecke How ever chanign them from my object to int, would this not mean they are no longer linked. 

As when I want to display them I need to go on item.Game.Title to get the title when displaying them. If i would do this would that not mean I just display the ID ?

Comment: You still need the `virtual` properties you had before e.g. - `public virtual Game Game { get; set; }`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I've redone it now so now my Game is linked with my GameId

So when I display Game it will display the title as I can go on Item.Game.Title

How would I link NextGame? As of right now I have to go on Item.NextGame but that will display the ID of that name, but I want it to have it display the title for that game aswell.

Comment: Since you have 2 foreign keys to the same object type, you going to need something like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11272990/two-same-class-types-in-entity-framework-class-issue) to distinguish them

Comment: @StephenMuecke you are a hero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `DropDownList()` methods in the view are trying to bind to typeof `Game` which is a complex object (a `<select>` only posts back a single value type). You need to bind to properties which are typeof `int`. Since you have 2 properties with foreign keys to the `Game` table, your properties should be

```
[ForeignKey("Game")]
public int GameId { get; set; }
public virtual Game Game { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("NextGame")]
public int NextGameId { get; set; }        
public virtual Game NextGame { get; set; }
```

Next, in the controller, you need only generate one select list if both dropdownlists will contain the same value

```
ViewBag.GameList= new SelectList(db.Games, "GameId", "GameTitle");
```

And in the view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.GameId, (SelectList)ViewBag.GameList , new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.NextGameId, (SelectList)ViewBag.GameList , new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Side note: Suggest you change your `Date` property to

```
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

and include a parameterless constructor to initialize the property to its default

```
public class Post
{
  public Post()
  {
    Date = DateTime.Today;
  }
```